# tcolorbox without background color (transparent)

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to have transparent background in tcolorbox.

Most time `colback=white` is a work-around but it is not clean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    title=Title,
%   opacityback=1,  % this does not work
%   colback=white,  % this is not what I want
]
This should have transparent backround. \\
Background should look yellow. 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see in the documentation : Transparency in the Option Key section

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to flav.

Transparent background in tcolorbox is only possible with the skin key `standard jigsaw`.  Otherwise there is no effect of the key `opacityback=0`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    standard jigsaw,
    title=Title,
    opacityback=0,  % this works only in combination with the key "standard jigsaw"
]
This should have transparent backround. \\
Background should look yellow. 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get transparent background with `enhanced` too. Try `opacityfill=0`

Comment: ``standard jigsaw, opacityback=0`` and ``enhanced, opacityfill=0`` do different things. I can see that here, where I have a figure inside a box inside a box:

Comment: Each of jigsaw styles works: `standard jigsaw`, `enhanced jigsaw`, and `bicolor jigsaw`. See `tcolorbox` package manual v6.2.0 (2024-01-10), sec. 10.11 "Jigsaw Skin Variants".

Answer (score 13):

You must use enhanced :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
  title=Title,
  opacityframe=.5,
   opacityback=.5,  % this does not work
%   colback=white,  % this is not what I want
]
This should have transparent backround. \\
Background should look yellow. 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this makes everything transparent. I just want to remove the background color from the main part of the box. My answert does exactly what I want and I found it because of your comment. Thanks again.